# for the length of each row in column Y duplicate row in column X

Tags: r, dataframe

(Please feel free to adjust title to something more fitting)

I have a `data.frame` with two columns, `X` and `Y` of class `list` as below

```
X <- list("A","B","C","D")
Y <- list("a",c("a", "b"),"c",c("a", "c", "d"))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y))
```

When column `Y` has two or more entries or as here characters, I would like for the length of each row in `Y` (number of characters) to correspond to the number of identical rows in column `X`. Easier put, for each character in `Y` their must be an individual row in `X`.

```
# desired output

X Y
A a
B a
B b
C c
D a
D c
D d
```

Im not sure how to go about this, so any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do elements in X ever have more than one item? How many columns are you actually dealing with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
do.call(rbind, Map(expand.grid, X, Y))
##   Var1 Var2
## 1    A    a
## 2    B    a
## 3    B    b
## 4    C    c
## 5    D    a
## 6    D    c
## 7    D    d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, list(Y = unlist(Y)), by = unlist(X)]
#    unlist Y
# 1:      A a
# 2:      B a
# 3:      B b
# 4:      C c
# 5:      D a
# 6:      D c
# 7:      D d
```

This will be much faster than the `Map` + `expand.grid` approach, even if you're only dealing with, say, 1000 rows; however, this will only work in its present form if each "row" of "X" has just one element.

---

Here's a function that should be able to handle lists with more than one element in more than one column, and should handle more than two columns quite easily.

```
egFun <- function(indf) {
  DT <- data.table(indf, keep.rownames=TRUE, key = "rn")
  out <- Reduce(function(x, y) x[y, allow.cartesian = TRUE], 
         lapply(setdiff(names(DT), "rn"), function(x) 
           DT[, list(unlist(get(x))), by = rn]))
  setnames(out, names(DT))
  out
}
```

Usage would be:

```
egFun(df)
```